# VB6, ADO, Asynchronous command and closing the connection

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous, vb6, ado

Quick question really, do I need to close an ADO command? I have read in several places that simply setting it to nothing does the same thing as closing it but I'm yet to find a definitive answer.

I have a VB6 routine that at runtime creates a connection and command object which execute asynchronously a stored procedure that doesn't return any results.

At the end of this routine both objects are set to nothing. The below code shows exactly what's performed

```
 ' Open connection
con.Open 
'
' Create command to execute stored proc
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = cSQLDelete
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter _
        ("@ExpiryDate=", adDate, adParamInput, 20, ExpiryDate)
'
' Run procedure, no results
cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords + adAsyncExecute
'
' Tidy up

Set cmd = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
```

Note the absence of con.Close. If this is inserted before the  con=nothing, the stored procedure does not run - I assume that since it's asynchronous it hasn't had time to execute before the connection is closed.

Without the con.Close, this works fine.

So, my question is what implications are there for not closing the connection. Will the connection simply timeout in the background?? Bear in mind that this function is called A LOT and so far testing hasn't shown any problems.

If I need to close the connection when the stored procedure finishes, how would I do this? Having a C# background, I'm unfamiliar with VB6 and find creating objects with events at runtime an awkward process.

p.s. Sql Server 2008

Thanks

Comment: I would encourage you to check the resources on the SQL Server box.  Specifically, connect to it using SQL Server Management Studio, open a query window and execute "sp_who".  I think you'll find a lot of lingering connections that could eventually slow down your SQL Server.  This is just a guess (which is why I did not put it as an answer).  Since it's super easy to check, I encourage you to try it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for command to complete or fail before tearing down the connection. Closing connection while command is executing will instantaneously raise an error, setting connection to nothing won't release the resources it is holding and may crash your program.

The correct method is to close the connection when the command completes, usually by monitoring the ExecuteComplete event (your connection must belong to a class or a form).

You can use a something similar:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents con As ADODB.Connection
Dim bExecuting As Boolean

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    If Not bExecuting Then Exit Sub

    If Not con Is Nothing Then
        con.Cancel
    End If
    bExecuting = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdExecute_Click()
    If bExecuting Then Exit Sub

    If con Is Nothing Then
        Set con = New ADODB.Connection
        con.Open "Provider=..."
    End If
    bExecuting = True
    con.Execute "WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:10'", , adExecuteNoRecords + adAsyncExecute
End Sub

Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
    If bExecuting Then Exit Sub
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub con_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    If Not pError Is Nothing Then Debug.Print pError.Description
    bExecuting = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    bExecuting = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
    If bExecuting Then Cancel = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload()
    If Not con Is Nothing Then
        If con.State = adStateOpen Then con.Close
        set con = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but where are you closing the connection?

Comment: Looks like Form_Unload was lost somewhere, I'll edit the code. Another good spot would be directly in con_ExecuteComplete.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm bit concerned how to apply it to my situation (btw the application is not mine !) - I'll explain. The function is called from a timer event that fires every 10ms - the app concerned is a "server" and within this event if there are no client requests to service, it performs house-keeping duties. One of these is to clear an audit db of old records. If the server is idle, then this task (i.e. the stored proc in question) could get called 1000x per minute (again, I didn't write this. continued in next comment....

Comment: The task is performed by instantiating Db class, calling its Delete method and disposing of class. Previously this was a synchronous call, which I've changed to async because this task could take a long time (10x seconds). Now the task is executed quickly and successfully only if I do not close the connection. If I do, the connnection is closed before the command completes (hence my question). I do not want the class to wait around until the command completes in case of any errors (e.g. command does not return) which would cause the server to hang indefinitely which would be very, very bad ...

Comment: ... it's a Process control server for a factory and so the factory would grind to a halt. SO, testing - without closing the connection - and just Nothing the reference, seems to work without any (obvious) side effects. But since I do not fully understand what's going on I'm a bit nervous about promoting the code to production...

Comment: Both comments are worthy and although did not answer my question directly, were informative and relevant so points awarded.

Comment: Thanks. How about using only one instance of housekeeping class (hiding the connection details inside and reporting back only the current job state or number of jobs still waiting) instead of instantiating a new copy in each call? Something similar to `If Not objHouseKeeping.IsRunning() Then objHouseKeeping.StartJob(params)` in you timer event if you don't need to queue jobs and only start them periodically or `If objHouseKeeping.JobsWaiting < 123456 Then objHouseKeeping.AddJob(params)` if upto 123456 jobs can be queued.

Answer (score 1):

What this code does is execute the command if the connection is not busy (State=Open). Otherwise put it on a stack and execute it when the current command completes.  My knowledge of VB arrays is limited so sorry its a bit ugly - there may be a better way to do a FIFO queue?

```
Dim WithEvents mobjAdoConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim CommandArray() As String

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim cmdNo As Integer
    If mobjAdoConn.State <> adStateOpen Then
       cmdNo = UBound(CommandArray)
       ReDim Preserve CommandArray(cmdNo + 1)
       CommandArray(cmdNo) = "WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:10'"
       Label2.Caption = cmdNo
    Else
        mobjAdoConn.Execute "WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:10'", , adExecuteNoRecords + adAsyncExecute
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo Err
    Set mobjAdoConn = New ADODB.Connection

    mobjAdoConn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
    mobjAdoConn.ConnectionString = "Provider..."

    mobjAdoConn.Open

    ReDim CommandArray(1)
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly

End Sub

Private Sub mobjAdoConn_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
Dim cmd As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim cmds As Integer
    cmds = UBound(CommandArray)
    If cmds > 1 Then
        cmd = CommandArray(1)
        If cmds = 2 Then
            ReDim CommandArray(1)
            Label2.Caption = 0
        Else
            For i = 2 To cmds - 1
                CommandArray(i - 1) = CommandArray(i)
            Next i
            ReDim Preserve CommandArray(cmds - 1)
            Label2.Caption = cmds - 2
        End If
        mobjAdoConn.Execute cmd, , adExecuteNoRecords + adAsyncExecute
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Collections are handy for FIFO/LIFO queues. The syntax is cleaner and performance should be better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm here because I'm considering using asynchExecute on a similar real-time application. The problem with setting the connection to nothing while it is open is that it may not get properly released and every 10Ms you create a new one, this could result in a memory leak.  Mucker you should monitor memory usage when you are testing this to see if it happens.

Comment: What you can do is use a string array to stack up database commands when the connection is busy and use the ExecuteComplete event to unstack them and execute them.

Comment: Thanks for the time taken here to provide a detailed answer. I have left the application running for 3 days and no errors, adverse memory usage was observed. So, this suggests that the way to execute an SP, which returns no records and you don't need to wait for the command to have executed (afterall it's a fire-and-forget command), this is the way to go. BTW, the server already uses a method similar to yours (collection, not an array) but services client requests before housekeeping ones....continued...

Comment: ... housekeeping tasks MUST take an instance to dispatch, even if the SP could take many seconds or minutes to execute. With having to wait for the command to execute, albeit asynchronously, before moving on doesn't appear to be the best approach. Client requests should only be cached if the server cannot process them quickly enough - not because it's waiting for a housekeeping task to finish. If a high pressure alarm goes off and it takes the server 30 seconds to react because of a housekeeping task running, questions will be asked.