# MySQL-Queries via ODBC from MS Access VBA: ADODB asynchronous execution does not work

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, adodb

I am using an Access Database as a frontend with MySQL as a backend. To save time with rather time intensive queries I would like to have the MySQL-Server run these in parallel.

Currently I cannot work out to tell VBA to send them asynchronously. My code is like this:

```
Do While ...
   Dim rs_newRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset
   Set rs_newRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
   rs_newRecordSet.Open Ext_TranslateQuery(str_query), Ext_Connection, , , adAsyncExecute
Loop
```

So during the Do while loop several queries are opened through a recordset with the option adAsyncExecute. The queries are all INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM-Queries, so I do not expected the recordsets to return anything.

Problem now is, that even though the adAsyncExecute-Option is specified, VBA seems to wait until the Recordset.Open-Command is finished. Furthermore, if I run a *show processlist* on the mysql schema I do see just one thread with an INSERT INTO ...-Query.

Why does VBA wait for the execution of the query and how can I change this?

Many thanks
Bastian

Comment: You should not be using `rs.Open` for action queries. Use `conn.Execute` instead.

Comment: Or better, create an `ADODB.Command` and `.Execute` that.

Comment: Thank you, switched to ADODB.Command

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping, I found the answer here:
[VB6, ADO, Asynchronous command and closing the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659411/vb6-ado-asynchronous-command-and-closing-the-connection)

You have to create a new connection for every recordset/command you want to execute in parallel because otherwise the query will be stacked on the connections execution list. Do not forget to close the connection after execution of each query.